# JPA deleted entity recreates entity on JoinColumn

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I have an entity with a `OneToOne` `JoinColumn` on another entity.  Something like :

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int idEntity1;
...
@Column(nullable = true)
private Integer idEntity2;
@OneToOne(optional=true)
@JoinColumn(insertable=false, updatable=false, nullable = true, name="idEntity2")
private Entity2Model entity2M;
```

As you can see I want to manage this entity myself (I don't want any insert or update).  In fact, I use `idEntity2` to manage the association myself.

I have to delete this entity.  Here is what I do :

1. delete `entity2M` (I can confirm it is correctly deleted in the database);
2. delete `entity1M`.

Problem is at step 2 `entity2M` is recreated.  I've found that it is because of my delete code which looks like :

```
public void delete(T entity) {
  T entityToBeRemoved = em.merge(entity);

  em.remove(entityToBeRemoved);
}
```

Obviously the `em.merge` recreates `entity2M`.  I know I can workaround this with `entity1M.setEntity2M(null);` just before the delete but I would really like to avoid this.

Why is `insertable=false, updatable=false` not enough to prevent this?

Comment: First of all, calling your attributes entities is really confusing. Stop that.  An entity refers to the table or the java class that represents that table.

Comment: Secondly, does your delete method offer any transactional functionality.  If not, you wont see the object being removed from the database until a transaction has been committed.

Comment: @ConMan The delete is wrapped inside a transaction which is committed correctly.  I can confirm that entity1 is removed and entity2 is recreated.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid explicit `entity1M.setEntity2M(null);` you can make use of the attribute `cascade={CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH}` within the `@OneToOne` annotation.

By excluding `CascadeType.MERGE` you prevent that this mapped field is being merged by an `EntityManager` instance. Thereby, the OR mapper will know that you don't want to merge (recreate) a (still) referenced entity (via its mapping partner).

So your code should look similar to:

```
@OneToOne(optional=true, cascade={CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
@JoinColumn(insertable=false, updatable=false, nullable = true, name="idEntity2")
private Entity2Model entity2M;
```

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I tried `cascade={CascadeType.REFRESH}`only but it didn't work. I discovered after that by default [OneToOne association are not cascaded](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.0.2/javax/persistence/OneToOne.html#cascade%28%29).

Comment: Ah now I understand your comment - as cascade is optional, right you are. maybe you can provide more code from the project?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  Unfortunately I can't think of anything else to provide.  My "problem" seems related to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13145045/jpa-hibernate-removing-child-entities and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11957461/eclipselink-merge-unexpected-cascade.